# Как убрать дублирование данных в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerviewadapter

Есть `RecyclerView` который берет данные с сервера, дальше сохраняет их в кэш телефона, и после отображает на устройстве. Проблема в том что у меня отображается в `RecyclerView` данные, которые берутся  с интернета и те который уже сохранились в кэш и вывелись в `RecyclerView`,то есть происходит дублирование, как его убрать?

Визуально это выглядит так

[image: Визуально это выглядит так]

`Fragment` где все это происходит

```
public class FragmentRink extends Fragment {
    List<ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2> mSkatingRinkScheduleList;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;
    String URL = "";
    String GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_NUMBER = "session_number";
    String GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_START = "session_start";
    String GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_END = "session_end";
    String GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_WEEKDAYS = "weekdays";
    String GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_WEEKDAYS_AND_HOLIDAYS = "weekends_and_holidays";
    RequestQueue requestQueue;


    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
            }
        };

        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rink, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        recyclerView = requireView().findViewById(R.id.recy_srs);

        mSkatingRinkScheduleList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerViewadapter = new AdapterSkatingRinkSchedule_2((ArrayList<ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2>) mSkatingRinkScheduleList);

        recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
        JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = requireView().findViewById(R.id.ref);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.color_8);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
            mSkatingRinkScheduleList.clear();
            JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        });
    }

    public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL() {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, response ->
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2 item = new ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2();
                    JSONObject json;
                    json = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    item.set_session_number(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_NUMBER));
                    item.set_session_start(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_START));
                    item.set_session_end(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_END));
                    item.set_weekdays(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_WEEKDAYS));
                    item.set_weekends_and_holidays(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_WEEKDAYS_AND_HOLIDAYS));

                    mSkatingRinkScheduleList.add(item);
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }

            recyclerViewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }, error ->
                Log.e("Volley", error.toString())) {
            @Override
            protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                try {
                    Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
                    if (cacheEntry == null) {
                        cacheEntry = new Cache.Entry();
                    }
                    final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;
                    cacheEntry.data = response.data;
                    cacheEntry.softTtl = now;
                    cacheEntry.ttl = ttl;
                    String headerValue;
                    headerValue = response.headers.get("Date");
                    if (headerValue != null) {
                        cacheEntry.serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
                    }
                    headerValue = response.headers.get("Last-Modified");
                    if (headerValue != null) {
                        cacheEntry.lastModified = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
                    }
                    cacheEntry.responseHeaders = response.headers;
                    final String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                    return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString), cacheEntry);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
                    return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void deliverResponse(JSONArray response) {
                super.deliverResponse(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
                super.deliverError(error);
            }

            @Override
            protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
                return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
            }
        };
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireContext());
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}
```

Мой `Аdapter`

```
public class AdapterSkatingRinkSchedule_2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSkatingRinkSchedule_2.SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder> {
    public List<ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2> mSkatingRinkScheduleList;

    public AdapterSkatingRinkSchedule_2(ArrayList<ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2> SkatingRinkScheduleList) {
        mSkatingRinkScheduleList = SkatingRinkScheduleList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_srs, parent, false);
        return new SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder(v);
    }

    public static class SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView number_srs, start_time_srs, end_time_srs, cost_1_srs, cost_2_srs;
        public LinearLayout ll_main;

        public SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ll_main = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_main);
            number_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_srs);
            start_time_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.start_time_srs);
            end_time_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.end_time_srs);
            cost_1_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cost_1_srs);
            cost_2_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cost_2_srs);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2 currentItem = mSkatingRinkScheduleList.get(position);
        holder.number_srs.setText(currentItem.get_session_number());
        holder.start_time_srs.setText(currentItem.get_session_start());
        holder.end_time_srs.setText(currentItem.get_session_end());
        holder.cost_1_srs.setText(currentItem.get_weekdays());
        holder.cost_2_srs.setText(currentItem.get_weekends_and_holidays());


        holder.ll_main.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DialogSkatingRinkSchedule dialogSRS = new DialogSkatingRinkSchedule();
            dialogSRS.show(((AppCompatActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(), "item");
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("number", currentItem.get_session_number());
            bundle.putString("start", currentItem.get_session_start());
            bundle.putString("end", currentItem.get_session_end());
            bundle.putString("w", currentItem.get_weekdays());
            bundle.putString("wah", currentItem.get_weekends_and_holidays());
            dialogSRS.setArguments(bundle);
        });
        holder.getAdapterPosition();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSkatingRinkScheduleList.size();
    }
}
```

Добавил `List< ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2> newArr = mSkatingRinkScheduleList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());`

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL() {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, response ->
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2 item = new ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2();
                    JSONObject json;
                    json = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    item.set_session_number(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_NUMBER));
                    item.set_session_start(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_START));
                    item.set_session_end(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_END));
                    item.set_weekdays(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_WEEKDAYS));
                    item.set_weekends_and_holidays(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_WEEKDAYS_AND_HOLIDAYS));
                    mSkatingRinkScheduleList.add(item);
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            List< ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2> newArr = mSkatingRinkScheduleList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
            recyclerViewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Покажите ваш адаптер

Comment: @Barmale Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял вы используете этот массив `mSkatingRinkScheduleList` добавляя в него элементы. Это у вас `List` судя по коду. Чтобы убрать дубликаты можно использовать кучу примочек типа [таких](https://www.baeldung.com/java-remove-duplicates-from-list). Но я бы вам советовал уйти от `List` в сторону `ArrayList< ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2>`. У данного типа массивов есть замечательный метод как `distinct`:

```
List< ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2> newArr = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

этот вызов можно разместить перед обновлением адаптера. Так же как вариант обновлять адаптер когда цикл достигает последнего элемента:

```
if(i== response.lastIndex()){
//update adapter
}
```

так же я бы вам советовал через логгирование или дебаг посмотреть на сам размер ответа от сервера, потому что я допускаю две причины такого поведения:

1. В ответе и правда 4 элемента
2. Вы неправильно обновляете ваш адаптер

Так же стоит посмотреть и на ваш адаптер в целом, потому что там тоже могут быть какие-то ошибки приведшие к такому неправильному поведению.

### UPDATE

я думаю так - вы грузите данные из кэша и потом дополнительно грузите данные с сервера, и по итогу получается 2+2. Попробуйте переподвязывать к виджету списка адаптер с данными. Если мое первое предложение верно, то это поведение вполне нормальное. То есть вам нужно проверить если есть кэш то запрос не слать, если запрос послали то привяжите заново новый адаптер к списку с полученными данными.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, добавил adapter. В ответе 2 элемента, они дублируются. Поменял `List` на `ArrayList` и попытался добавить `List< ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2> newArr = mSkatingRinkScheduleList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());` но это не помогло, данные также дублируются.

Comment: а вы данные только один раз запрашиваете или два? может я по коду что-то не понял)

Comment: В onViewCreated я вызываю `JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL()` один раз. Дальше `jsonArrayRequest`  отображает данные, и если я правильно разобрался то `parseNetworkResponse` сохраняет данные в кэш и выводит их в тот же `RecyclerView` в котором отображает данные и `jsonArrayRequest`

Comment: Обновил ответ, и так же измените в адаптере на ArrayList тоже, тогда приводить типы данных не придется

Comment: Вы все верно понимаете, вся проблема что я не знаю как написать код чтобы это реализовать, правильно ли я понял, нужно создать ещё один `Adapter` в который будут сохраняться данные из прошлого запроса и выводиться в случае если кэш не обнаружен?

Comment: да, вам нужно подвязывать новый адаптер с данными, и очищать адаптер когда вы пытаетесь загрузить данные. Так же если вы знаете как в логи вывести сообщение, то попробуйте просмотреть места где вы создаете адаптер и места где грузите данные

Comment: У меня не получается создать создать подобного рода `Adapter` есть какой-нибудь пример или могли бы вы помочь его написать?

Comment: Получилось сделать, только я не использовал ещё один `Adapter`,добавлю ответ как у меня получилось реализовать задуманное

Comment: рад что у вас получилось) суть того что вы не создаете адаптер как класс или что-то типа такого, а просто подвязываете к списку новый адаптер как уже делали и все

Answer (score 0):

Я смог реализовать задуманное следующим образом, ранее я создал метод `JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL` на который ссылался в `onViewCreated`. В `JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL` у меня всё шло подряд, сначала я хотел просто очищать ненужную часть списка и оставлять ту которая сохраняется в кэш. Итак, как же сделал я, в первую очередь разделил на 2 части `JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL2` и `JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL`, таким образом у меня запускается нужная часть. Надеюсь кому-то поможет.

`JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL`

```
 public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array) {
        mSkatingRinkScheduleList.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2 GetDataAdapter2 = new ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2();
            JSONObject json;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                GetDataAdapter2.set_session_number(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_NUMBER));
                GetDataAdapter2.set_session_start(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_START));
                GetDataAdapter2.set_session_end(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_END));
                GetDataAdapter2.set_weekdays(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_WEEKDAYS));
                GetDataAdapter2.set_weekends_and_holidays(json.getString(GET_JSON_FROM_SERVER_WEEKDAYS_AND_HOLIDAYS));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mSkatingRinkScheduleList.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }
        recyclerViewadapter = new AdapterSkatingRinkSchedule_2((ArrayList<ItemSkatingRinkSchedule_2>) mSkatingRinkScheduleList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
```

`JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL2`

```
public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL2() {
        jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
                this::JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL,
                error ->
                Log.e("Volley", error.toString())) {
            @Override
            protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                try {
                    Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
                    if (cacheEntry == null) {
                        cacheEntry = new Cache.Entry();
                    }
                    final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;
                    cacheEntry.data = response.data;
                    cacheEntry.softTtl = now;
                    cacheEntry.ttl = ttl;
                    String headerValue;
                    headerValue = response.headers.get("Date");
                    if (headerValue != null) {
                        cacheEntry.serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
                    }
                    headerValue = response.headers.get("Last-Modified");
                    if (headerValue != null) {
                        cacheEntry.lastModified = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
                    }
                    cacheEntry.responseHeaders = response.headers;
                    final String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                    return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString), cacheEntry);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
                    return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void deliverResponse(JSONArray response) {
                super.deliverResponse(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
                super.deliverError(error);
            }

            @Override
            protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
                return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
            }
        };
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
```